# How does one use the dataframe merge, but still include NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to have NaN values, but after I merge, some of my values are going away.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'tic':['PYPL','PYPL','PYPL'],
        'fyear':['2017','2018','2019'],
        'asset':[40774,43332,51333],
        'debt':[0,0,5368],
        'ni':[1795,2057,2459],
       }
data2 = {'tic':['SQ','SQ','SQ'],
        'fyear':['2017','2018','2019'],
        'asset':[2187.27,3281.023,4551.258],
        'debt':[362.404,1051.141,1047.662],
        'ni':[-62.813,-38.453,375.446],
       }
data3 = {'tic':['GPN','GPN','GPN'],
        'fyear':['2017','2018','2019'],
        'asset':[12998.069,13230.774,44480.162],
        'debt':[4559.408,5015.168,9487.852],
        'ni':[468.425,452.053,430.613],
       }
data4 = {'fyear':['2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2015','2016'],
         'tic':['PYPL','PYPL','PYPL','PYPL','PYPL','SQ','SQ','SQ','SQ','SQ','GPN','GPN'],
         'price':[36.2,39.47,73.62,84.09,108.17,13.09,13.63,34.67,56.09,62.56,104.38,77.69],
    
}
PYPL = pd.DataFrame(data1)
SG = pd.DataFrame (data2)
gpn = pd.DataFrame (data3)
prc = pd.DataFrame (data4)

frame = pd.concat([PYPL,SG,gpn])

frame.merge(prc)
```

This gives me a truncated dataframe, but unfortunately I'm trying to include more with what I'm trying to do.

```
fyear stk_ticker price asset debt ni
0 2015 PYPL 36.20 NaN NaN NaN
1 2016 PYPL 39.47 NaN NaN NaN
2 2017 PYPL 73.62 40774.000 0.000 1795.000
3 2018 PYPL 84.09 43332.000 0.000 2057.000
4 2019 PYPL 108.17 51333.000 5368.000 2459.000
5 2015 SQ 13.09 NaN NaN NaN
6 2016 SQ 13.63 NaN NaN NaN
7 2017 SQ 34.67 2187.270 362.404 -62.813
8 2018 SQ 56.09 3281.023 1051.140 -38.453
9 2019 SQ 62.56 4551.258 1047.662 375.446
10 2014 GPN 104.38 NaN NaN NaN
11 2015 GPN 77.69 NaN NaN NaN
12 2016 GPN 69.41 NaN NaN NaN
13 2017 GPN 100.24 12998.069 4559.408 468.425
14 2018 GPN 103.13 13230.774 5015.168 452.053
15 2019 GPN 182.56 44480.162 9487.852 430.613
```

This is what I'm trying to get. I'm not sure if i have to concatenate or merge them together?

Comment: maybe you want `how='left'`  in your `.merge()`

Comment: try `frame.merge(prc,how='left')`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `how='right'`:

```
df = frame.merge(prc, how='right')
print(df)

     tic fyear      asset      debt        ni   price
0   PYPL  2015        NaN       NaN       NaN   36.20
1   PYPL  2016        NaN       NaN       NaN   39.47
2   PYPL  2017  40774.000     0.000  1795.000   73.62
3   PYPL  2018  43332.000     0.000  2057.000   84.09
4   PYPL  2019  51333.000  5368.000  2459.000  108.17
5     SQ  2015        NaN       NaN       NaN   13.09
6     SQ  2016        NaN       NaN       NaN   13.63
7     SQ  2017   2187.270   362.404   -62.813   34.67
8     SQ  2018   3281.023  1051.141   -38.453   56.09
9     SQ  2019   4551.258  1047.662   375.446   62.56
10   GPN  2015        NaN       NaN       NaN  104.38
11   GPN  2016        NaN       NaN       NaN   77.69
```

Comment: Strange, I added it into my thing and it didn't work. Also, what if i want to have price instead of asset first, should i put prc.merge(frame)?

Comment: It's giving me something akin to a concatenate, and it's sorting by fyear, showing PYPL 2017-2019, and then showing PYPL 2015-2016 later.